# Allow PHP function to be called dynamically and statically

Tags: php, methods, dynamic, static, chaining

I'm building an application, and I need to be able to chain methods, so I will need to be able to call methods dynamically and statically.

For example:

```
$results = Class::where('something')
                ->where('something else');
```

In this case, the method 'where' needs to be called statically and dynamically, and still be allowed to be chained.

I know Laravel has something like this with Eloquent, but I do not know how to implement something like this.

Comment: more code please :) , anyways, if you want to do this you have to return your object from the `where` function

Comment: If you know Laravel does it, why not simply look at the Laravel code? [Here's the relevant code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1323)

Comment: Laravel uses facades. Static call to a facade `Class::where('something')` returns an instance of another class on which `->where('something else');` is being called. As a side note, you misuse term 'called dynamically'.

Comment: he wants to implement this li ke Laravel, he's not using Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of pure interest I've found a way to do this using `__call` and `__callStatic` and setting the methods you want to call to be inaccessible to the scope that is calling it (i.e. set the methods as `private` or `protected`).

**Important warning**: Using `__call` or `__callStatic` can lead to unexpected behavior! First read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#119407) to make sure you understand this. The code below dynamically executes the private class methods called from outside the class, so you need to be sure to whitelist specific methods that you want to add this behavior to. There may be other security issues that I have not dealt with, so use at your own risk.

```
class MethodTest
{

    private static $obj;
    private $fruit = 'watermelon';

    private function handleDynamicCallType($name, $arguments)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'method1':
            case 'method2':
                $this->{$name}($arguments);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid name");
        }
    }

    private function method1() {
        echo $this->fruit . ' ';
    }

    private function method2() {
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        if (!empty($arg_list[0][0])) {
            $this->fruit = $arg_list[0][0];
        }
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $this->handleDynamicCallType($name, $arguments);
        return $this;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$obj)) {
            self::getNewStaticInstance();
        }
        self::$obj->{$name}($arguments);
        return self::$obj;
    }

    public static function getNewStaticInstance()
    {
        self::$obj = new MethodTest();
        return self::$obj;
    }
}

$obj = new MethodTest;
$obj->method1()::method2('orange')->method1();
echo PHP_EOL;
MethodTest::method1()->method2('plum')::method1();
```

### Output:

```
watermelon orange 
orange plum
```

However the static object retains its properties after being called previously (notice the two `orange` strings). If this is undesired, we can force it to reset by calling `getNewStaticInstance()`:

```
MethodTest::method1()::method2('plum')::method1()::getNewStaticInstance()::method1();
```

### Output:

```
watermelon plum watermelon
```

Answer (score 2):

I just surprised myself by proving that this *is* indeed possible:

```
<?php
class Test {
    private static $myself;
    public function do() {
        echo isset($this) ? 'd' : 's';
        if (!isset(self::$myself)) {
            self::$myself = new self;
        }
        return self::$myself;
    }
    public static function done() {
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
Test::do()->do()->do()->done();
$myTest = new Test;
$myTest->do()->do()->do()->done();
$myTest::do()->do()->do()->done();
$myTest::do()->do()::do()->done();
Test::do()->do()->do()->done();
```

The output is:

```
sdd
ddd
sdd
sds
sdd
```

*But it is unbelievable bad style in my eyes...*

Comment: it is `Class::where('something')` in the question. Not `$class::where('something')`

Comment: Sorry, I had to revise the answer, the former version only _appeared_ to be working, fixed that. The credit goes to @Bamar and his answer here!

Comment: Since my answer presumably doesn't work for the same reason your original one didn't, I've deleted mine. You can have the rep for working out the winning combination.

Comment: Singleton *all* the DB classes!

Comment: @Sammitch Is that your general perspective of the world? Or does this have anything do to with this topic?

Comment: @arkascha There must be some other way that Laravel accomplishes this since this only works without producing warnings on HHVM. Calling a non-static method statically is deprecated as of PHP 7. https://3v4l.org/hrDcd. Also I had to rename `do()` since that produces a syntax error in PHP 5.6.

Comment: @Mike Interesting... I do _not_ get any warnings on standard php-7.0.15, though I only tested on CLI, obviously.

Comment: @Mike Ah, dang, no you are right, I do get warnings too, just didn't visualize them. My fault!

Comment: @Mike Oh, interesting: simply declaring method `do()` static too fix that, I get _no_ warnings or anything any more.

Comment: @arkascha You're right, it fixed the errors. However making `do()` static changes the output to 's' every time.

Comment: @Mike Indeed, the old issue again. Hmmm

Comment: @arkascha Maybe it doesn't matter that the class knows whether it was called statically or non-statically. Nothing in the question would indicate that. The OP just wants it to be able to chain.